# Google+ Interactive Post Deep Link to your Android App

Tags: android, google-plus, deep-linking

I am trying to invite friends through Google+ to answer my question on my app (G+ interactive post to let them launch my app and parse the question id).

My app is able to share an interactive post with Call to Action Button and with Deep Link on Google+, but I am having trouble getting this deep link to launch my app from Google+. If I include deep link URI with website url, it will just launch browser, and if I include deep link URI with custom scheme, it will be an invalid link.

I am following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/deep-link

This tutorial has a deep link to a web page, and I tried changing the scheme from http to a custom one for my app like this deep link id:

```
String deepLinkString = "myapp://view_poll/poll_id=1";
```

And this is how I set up the deep link URI for sharing on Google+ (through my app):

```
builder.addCallToAction(
            "VIEW", /** call-to-action button label */
            Uri.parse(deepLinkString), /** call-to-action url (for desktop use) */
            deepLinkString /** call to action deep-link ID (for mobile use), 512 characters or fewer */);

    // Set the content url (for desktop use).
    builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(deepLinkString));

    // Set the target deep-link ID (for mobile use).
    builder.setContentDeepLinkId(deepLinkString,
            null, null, null);
```

My app listens for the deep link:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activity.ParseDeepLinkActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.plus.VIEW_DEEP_LINK" />
        <data android:scheme="vnd.google.deeplink" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
...
```

I also tried:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activity.ParseDeepLinkActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data
            android:scheme="snappoll"
            android:host="view_poll" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
...
```

When I try this command on adb:

> $ adb shell am start
>           -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
>           -d "myapp://view_poll"

I see that my app launches the correct activity and receive the intent (when I have  in the manifest). However, I'm not sure how Google+ post make this happen, or what I should modify

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am also trying to understand how this works: sometimes (depending on deep link uri, my post is not actually posted on Google+, even though I get a message "Your post has been shared" and no error from Google + api.